# PHP Native Function to Filter Common Text Fields

Tags: php, security, input, filtering

Is there a native PHP function for rejecting invalid $_POST data from simple text fields?

Currently I'm using custom filter functions with regular expressions, and would really like to simplify my code if possible.

For example, let's say I have a form field for entering a last name. I want to check the submitted value and immediately reject the input if it contains any invalid characters.

Here are my criteria for considering PHP functions:

- A person's last name might be "Smith-Johnson", "Van Buren", "O'Malley", etc., so the function needs to tolerate spaces, hyphens, apostrophes, etc.
- My goal is to test the input and reject it right away -- as opposed to sanitizing it and running it through additional filters and processing steps.
- Two examples of input that I want to catch are:

  ```
  username' --
  username; DELETE FROM users;
  ```

Here are the options I'm aware of and why I have doubts about using them...

1. **is_string():** This function doesn't seem to catch either of the two examples above
2. **addslashes():** This function fails the second criterion
3. **htmlentities(), htmlspecialchars():** Same as addslashes(); if input is invalid, I don't want to keep working with it, even if it's sanitized
4. **strip_tags():** Fails the second criterion, but preferred over #3 because it eliminates unwanted characters rather than sanitizing them
5. **filter_input(...FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING):** As far as I can tell, this is identical to strip_tags(). **
6. **ctype_alpha(), ctype_alnum():** Fails the first criteria because it doesn't allow spaces and other characters.
7. **Regex/Custom Functions:** This is what I've been using. I'd really prefer to simplify my code and eliminate the (albeit minimal) regex overhead.

--

** Just curious: does PECL make filter_input() faster than strip_tags()?

Comment: Use PDO with placeholders to properly prevent SQL injection. For XSS injection I tend to use htmlentities unless I want to support some HTML tags. In that case I create a filter of allowed tags using an HTML parser.

Comment: Use proper encoding and everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks - I agree with both of these best practices and apply them both in my code. I'm interested in rejecting the input before ever reaching the point of preparing the query or output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function. You're asking basically how to tell one string from another one while they're both strings with complex criteria. That's quite a vague task for a "native" function.

The most "native" way of achieving that is to use regular expressions, and that's what you're already doing.

It is also against the ideology as $_POST and $_GET are supposed to represent parameters in their raw form, not after passing some validation.

Answer (score 0):

I always use regular expressions to validate form input. I have a whole suite of form validation and creation functions that I have developed over the years if you are interested.